# Como chamar um método de uma classe em outra classe

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Havia postado mais cedo mas não consegui editar, tentarei ser mais clara dessa vez. Estou fazendo (tentando)um code pra conta telefonica. Tenho a classe tempo, ligação e contadaligacao. na classe conta ligacao eu chamo um campo tipo tempo(classe) para converter o tempo em minutos e exibi-lo chamando da classe tempo um construtor.Tenho também na classe ligação um outro campo que retorna o valor do minuto. O que eu gostaria de fazer é chamar tanto o método que me retorna o valor, quando o que retorna os minutos, para dentro da classe condadaligacao. A questão, é que não estou conseguindo chamar essas funções, e como sou iniciante nem ao menos sei o que estou fazendo de errado.

Seguem abaixo minhas classes:

```
public class Ligacao
{
    private String nrOrigem, localOrig, nrDest, localDest;
    private float valor;
    private Tempo inicio, termino;


    public Ligacao(String nrOrigem, String localOrig, String nrDest, String localDest, float valor, Tempo inicio, Tempo termino){
    this.nrOrigem=nrOrigem;
    this.localOrig=localOrig;
    this.nrDest=nrDest;
    this.localDest=localDest;
    this.valor=valor;
    this.inicio=inicio;
    this.termino=termino;
   }

   public String getnrOrigem(){
    return nrOrigem;
    }
   public void setnrOrigem(String numOrigem){
       this.nrOrigem=numOrigem;
    }

   public String getlocalOrig(){
   return localOrig;
    }
   public void setlocalOrig(String localOrigem){
   this.localOrig=localOrigem;
   }
   public String getnrDest(){
    return nrDest;
    }
   public void setnrDest(String numDest){
    this.nrDest=numDest;
    }
   public String getlocalDest(){
    return localDest;
    }
    public void setlocalDest(String localDest){
    this.localDest=localDest;
    }

    public float getvalor(){
    return valor;
    }
    public void setvalor(float valor){
        this.valor=valor;
    }
    public Tempo getinicio(){
        return inicio;
    }
    public Tempo gettermino(){
        return termino;
    }
    public int calcularDuracao(){
        int inicioSeg,terminoSeg,durSeg,durMin,resto;

        inicioSeg=inicio.tempoEmSegundos();
        terminoSeg=termino.tempoEmSegundos();

        durSeg=terminoSeg-inicioSeg;
        durMin=durSeg/60;
        resto=durSeg%2;
        if(resto>0){
            durMin++;
        }
        return durMin;
    }

    public boolean verificaNumero(String numero){
        return ((nrOrigem.equals(numero))||(nrDest.equals(numero)));

    }



}



public class Tempo
{
   private int hora, minuto, segundo;
   private float tempoTotal;


  public Tempo (int hora, int minuto, int segundo){
      this.hora=hora;
      this.minuto=minuto;
      this.segundo=segundo;
    }
    public int tempoEmSegundos(){
        return hora*3600 + minuto *60 + segundo;
    }
   public int gethora(){
    return this.hora;
    }
   public void sethora(int hora){
    this.hora = hora;
    }
    public int getminuto(){
    return this.minuto;
    }
    public void setminuto(int minuto){
    this.minuto=minuto;
    }
    public int getsegundo(){
    return this.segundo;
    }
    public void setsegundo(int segundo){
        this.segundo=segundo;
    }

}



public class ContaTel
{
    private int mes, ano, contrato;
    private Ligacao[] listaligacoes;
    private Tempo inicio,termino;

    public ContaTel(int mes,int ano, int contrato, int tamanho){
    this.mes=mes;
    this.ano=ano;
    this.contrato=contrato;
    this.listaligacoes = new Ligacao[tamanho];

    }
    public void setmes(int mes){
    this.mes= mes;
    }
    public int getmes(){
    return mes;
    }
    public void setano(int ano){
    this.ano = ano;

    } 
    public int getano(){
    return ano;
    }
    public void setcontrato(int contrato){
    this.contrato = contrato;
    }
    public int getcontrato(){
    return contrato;
    }
    public Ligacao[] getlistaligacoes(){
    return this.listaligacoes;
    }
    public void addligacao(Ligacao lig){
        int i=0;
         for(i=0;i<listaligacoes.length;i++){
            if (listaligacoes[i]==null){
                listaligacoes[i]=lig;
                break;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Não quero a resposta, quero aprender, fiquei o dia todo nisso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem a lista (vetor) de tudo dentro da `ContaTel`. Para você acessar essas funções você precisa primeiro acessar cada elemento da `Ligacao[]`.

```
public class ContaTel
{
    private int mes, ano, contrato;
    private Ligacao[] listaligacoes;
    private Tempo inicio,termino; // Desnecessário esses atributos

    ...

    public void doItAnywway(){

        for(int i = 0; i < listaligacoes.lenght; i++){

            Ligacao ligacao = listaligacoes[i]; // peguei um elemento
            Tempo t1 = ligacao.getinicio(); // peguei o Tempo deste elemento
            Tempo t2 = ligacao.gettermino(); // peguei o outro tempo deste elemento

            /**
            * Agora eu posso acessar todas as funções que eu precisar!!!!
            * VIVAAA!!!!
            */

            t1.tempoEmSegundos(); // usei essa!
            t1.gethora(); // peguei a hora!

            ligacao.calcularDuracao(); // essa parece boa!
            ligacao.getlocalDest(); // preciso ver para onde esse povo ligou!!!

        }

    }

    ...
```

Sei que você ainda está aprendendo mas precisa dar uma melhorada nessa modelagem sua.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Com modelagem vc diz a identação do código? se sim, onde eu posso ver mais sobre a padronização? E muito obrigada pela resposta!

Comment: @MarcelaBraga modelagem, é o que você fez. Você criou uma classe `ContaTel` que poderia ter mais de uma ligação, e que a ligação dependia de um Tempo para existir. Você criou as "regras". Porém, tem uns buracos... Tipo... a classe ContaTel não tem porque ter o atributo Tempo. Esse Tempo faz parte da ligação e não da conta. Entendeu?

Comment: @MarcelaBraga pesquise sobre UML e diagrama de classes.

Comment: Certo, de todo modo, eu estou tentando e está me retornando uma excessão aqui: 
    java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ContaTel.valorConta(ContaTel.java:52)

Comment: @MarcelaBraga ai já é outro problema! Mas você já consegue acessar as funções. Pesquise sobre esse erro no google.

Answer (score 0):

Não consegui entender muito bem o que você quer fazer, mas como você falou que quer aprender vou tentar explicar de um jeito meio genérico. Tem dois meios de você chamar métodos de uma classe:

1 - Instanciado ela

```
Classe classe = new Classe();
classe.metodo(parametrosSeHouver);
```

2 - Tornando o método da classe estático

2.1 - Declarando um metodo estatico

```
public static String retornaString(String str){
return str;
}
```

2.2 - Chamando um método estático:

```
Classe.retornaString("Uma string qualquer");
```

--- edit

```
public int calculaValorLigacao() {
    return calcularDuracao() * 1;       
}
```

Comment: Então, quero calcular o valor de uma ligação, a partir dos minutos. por exemplo, 200 minutosx1 real=200 reais. Não deve ter ficado muito claro, mas eu criei uma variável com o tipo da classe tempo, que recebe horas minutos e segundos, converte em minutos etc, e um método que armazena o valor da ligação. somente.

Comment: acho que entendi, veja a minha resposta atualizada, você já tinha na classe ligação um método que calculava a duração, então só criei um novo e multipliquei pelo valor do minuto